# Update Event with Google Calendar API Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

how can i update calendar events with the help of the Google Calendar API (v3) in javascript? I can not find any good example. List, delete and add is working fine for me but still could not get the update function working.

I tried it with this example

```
//This is the event data you got, with the changed values, you want to be changed in Calendar API
var changedEventData;

//changing the data of an calendar event
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calendarId + "/events/" + eventId,
  method: "PUT",
  data: changedEventData
});
```

From this Question:

[How to update an event in Google Calendar using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316961/how-to-update-an-event-in-google-calendar-using-javascript)

But the server responses with a 403 Exception

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update), updating of Calendar events can be done by sending HTTP request with the following format:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

Please note that this requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) with added scope of access.

For the encountered 403 Exception and other possible errors, suggested actions are given in [Handle API Errors](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors).

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! I did it now just by deleting the old event and insert the new event instead of update it.