# How do I create/change a Google Calendar Event with a given Meet URL using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, url, events, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create or update a Google Calendar Event using a previously generated Meet URL.
I've tried with something like this:

```
  var event = eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, options);      
  var eventId = event.getId().split("@")[0];

  var event1 = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  event1.setHangoutLink(room); //OLD Meet URL
  Calendar.Events.update(event1, calendarId, event1.id);
  var room1 = event1.hangoutLink;
```

Everything seems to be fine, from the last row I obtain that room1 == room, but the Event gets created with a new Meet URL! The one I get adding:

```
  var newRoom = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).hangoutLink;
```

after the previous code.
I also tried .patch() with the same result. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unfortunately this is currently not possible

Indeed, the [documentation for the event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) specifies:

> hangoutLink
> An absolute link to the Google+ hangout associated with  this event. **Read-only**.

On Google's Issue Tracker there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760708) for implementing the manual setting of the Hangout link. I recommen you to "star" the issue to increase the visibility and receive notifications about the implementaiton of the feature.

Comment: I see, but since it is possible to change/force the Meet Link with Google Calendar, isn't a bit strange that the same functionality is not accessible through Google Calendar APIs?

Comment: By far not all UI functionalitites are incorporated into the APIs. This is why Google offers the possibility to file feature requests - if many users are interested in a feature, it is likely that eventually it will be incorporated.

Comment: I understand but there is still something unclear. In this sequence:  
`var event = eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, options);  
var event1 =  Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);  
var room1  = event1.hangoutLink; event1.setHangoutLink(room);
var room2 = event1.hangoutLink;  
Calendar.Events.update(event1, calendarId, event1.id);  
var newRoom = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).hangoutLink;`  
I obtain that room2==room (event1 seems to change) but, at the end, newRoom==room1! So the Event taken from the Calendar changes but not the original one...

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you. Can you please provide reference to the documentaiton about the method `setHangoutLink` for Javascript? `Event taken from the Calendar changes but not the original one` - the original calendar event will not change until you push the changes through with `Calendar.Events.update`. If you assign a new `hangoutLink` to your variable `event1`, you are not actually updating the real event resource but only assigning a value to an object locally.

Comment: To update an event, you have to provide a resource body including the obligatory parameters `start` and `end` time - as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523473/11599789), however, if you provide a `hangoutLink` this part of the request will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will stop trying to set the link until an API update will finally enable it. :)

Comment: Sorry not to be able to give you better news.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible using the [Advanced Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) service in Apps script which should allow you to access [the API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#javascrip)

[This article](https://yamm.com/blog/create-calendar-events-with-google-meet-links-using-the-calendar-api-and-google-apps-script/) shows the use of the Calendar API in Apps Script

On this [dev reference page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) you can see that the `conferenceData.conferenceId` value can be set to the 10-letter meeting code, for example aaa-bbbb-ccc. Prior to setting this, it appears that you need to set the key `type` to `"hangoutsMeet"` in the `conferenceData.conferenceSolution` object

After all the above, I searched SO again and I find [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785196/create-a-google-calendar-event-with-a-specified-google-meet-id-conferencedata-c) with a full worked answer