# Create a Google Calendar event with a specified Google Meet ID, conferenceData.conferenceId

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am wondering why the following function creates an event with a random meet ID instead of the `conferenceId` I specified. The `conferenceId` can't be programmatically set as I want? I can set the meet ID by clicking on the event in the Google Calendar. How can I set the meet ID programmatically using Google API?

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource

```
function createEventWithConference() {
  const calendarId = "primary"; // Change to the desired calendar ID
  const conferenceId = "qsz-pkbc-tnx"; // Set the conference ID
  const event = {
    summary: 'Example Event',
    location: 'Online',
    description: 'This is an example event created with Google Calendar API',
    start: {
      dateTime: '2023-03-20T10:00:00',
      timeZone: 'America/New_York'
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: '2023-03-20T11:00:00',
      timeZone: 'America/New_York'
    },
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet'
        },
        requestId: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
      },
      conferenceId: conferenceId // Set the conference ID
    }
  };

  const response = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId, {
    conferenceDataVersion: 1
  });

  Logger.log("Event created: %s", response.htmlLink);
}
```

I tried to use update and patch method after creating an event using the function above hoping that I could replace the meet ID with `conferenceId`, but I still couldn't plug the `conferenceId` into the event.

```
function updateConferenceId() {
  const eventId = "opb4l88pk0v7ap6fejt6bcg7dg";
  const conferenceId = "xon-qzov-sjy"; 
  const event = Calendar.Events.get('primary', eventId);

  event.conferenceData = {
    createRequest: {
      conferenceSolutionKey: {
        type: 'hangoutsMeet'
      },
      conferenceId: conferenceId
    }
  };

  // Update the event with the new conference ID
  const updatedEvent = Calendar.Events.update(event, 'primary', event.id, {
    conferenceDataVersion: 1
  });
}


function patchConferenceId() {
  const eventId = 'opb4l88pk0v7ap6fejt6bcg7dg'; 
  const conferenceId = 'xon-qzov-sjy'; 
  const event = Calendar.Events.get('primary', eventId);

  event.conferenceData = {
    createRequest: {
      conferenceSolutionKey: {
        type: 'hangoutsMeet'
      },
      conferenceId: conferenceId
    }
  };
  
  const updatedEvent = Calendar.Events.patch(event, 'primary', eventId, { 
    conferenceDataVersion: 1 
  });
}
```

Comment: You set the conferenceId in the `conferenceData.createRequest`but should be in the `conferenceData`. Maybe it can solve this.

Comment: @OneQ Thank you for the input. I changed the code as above so that `conferenceId` is in the `conferenceData`. But I still get a random meet ID rather than the `conferenceId`.

Comment: I can see the problem is related to the `conferenceData.createRequest` as you need to use put the meeting info in `conferenceData.entryPoints` instead. I posted an answer to explain a bit more with a sample code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are using `createRequest` instead of `entryPoints` within your code to modify the meeting link. According to the official documentation either one of them is required, but one is used to ask Google to generate a new Google Meet link randomly when you do not have one, and the other one is to edit or set the actual Google Meet info of the event:

> Either conferenceSolution and at least one entryPoint, or createRequest is required.

#### createRequest:

> A request to generate a new conference and attach it to the event.

#### entryPoint:

> Information about individual conference entry points, such as URLs or phone numbers.

#### Sample code:

```
function createNewEventWithMeet() {
  const calendarId = "primary";
  const meetURL = "xon-qzov-sjy";
  const resource = {
    start: { dateTime: "2023-03-20T00:00:00.000+09:00" },
    end: { dateTime: "2023-03-20T00:30:00.000+09:00" },
    hangoutLink: `https://meet.google.com/${meetURL}`,
    conferenceData: {
      conferenceId: meetURL,
      entryPoints: [
        {
          entryPointType: "video",
          uri: `https://meet.google.com/${meetURL}`,
          label: `meet.google.com/${meetURL}`
        }
      ],
      conferenceSolution: {
        key: {
          type: "hangoutsMeet"
        }
      }
    },
    summary: "sample event with Meet link",
    description: "sample description",
  };
  const res = Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId, {
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
  });
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [conferenceData.entryPoints[]](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#:%7E:text=no%20entry%20points.-,conferenceData.entryPoints%5B%5D,-list)
- [Sample Scripts for Creating New Event with Google Meet Link to Google Calendar using Various Languages](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/94791d48823e9659aa376cf7f0161d9b)

Comment: Your code works nicely! I now can creat the event with the meet ID that I want! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just clicked the accept button. Thanks again for the comment!