# google meeting with Google_Service_Calendar_EntryPoint not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a problem creating a google calendar event with video entry point type.
Basically my EntryPoint parameters have no impact on the calendar event. It just creates it.
If I am using the Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest, the meeting is added, but of course no password is added.

This is the php code:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($googleClient);

        $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($googleClient, false, null, 'batch/calendar/v3');

        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(
            [
                'id'          => 'uniqueid'.rand(),
                'summary'     => 'testmeeting',
                'description' => 'testmeeting',
                'start'       => [
                    'dateTime' => $start_datetime,
                    'timeZone' => $timezone,
                ],
                'end'         => [
                    'dateTime' => $end_datetime,
                    'timeZone' => $timezone,
                ]
            ]
        );
        $meetUrl = 'tgu-igjc-sgs';
        $conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
        $event->setHangoutLink('https://meet.google.com/'.$meetUrl);
        $conferenceSolutionKey = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolutionKey();
        $conferenceSolutionKey->setType('hangoutsMeet');
        $conference->setConferenceId($meetUrl);
        $conferenceSolution = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceSolution();
        $conferenceSolution->setKey($conferenceSolutionKey);
        $conference->setConferenceSolution($conferenceSolution);

//            $conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
//            $conferenceRequest->setRequestId($event->id);
//            $conferenceRequest->setConferenceSolutionKey($conferenceSolutionKey);
//            $conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);

        $conferenceEntryPoint = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EntryPoint();
        $conferenceEntryPoint->setEntryPointType('video');
        $conferenceEntryPoint->setUri('https://meet.google.com/'.$meetUrl);
        $conferenceEntryPoint->setLabel('https://meet.google.com/'.$meetUrl);
        $conferenceEntryPoint->setPassword('testpassword');
        $conference->setEntryPoints($conferenceEntryPoint);

        $event->setConferenceData($conference);

        $req =  $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

        $batch->add($req);
        $batch->execute();
```

I used as a reference [Create a Google Calendar event with a specified Google Meet ID, conferenceData.conferenceId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785196/create-a-google-calendar-event-with-a-specified-google-meet-id-conferencedata-c)

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? Thanks